# Add border to dots PCA analysis

Tags: r, pca, factoextra

I would like to add a border to the dots, this will allow me to use the color white.

I have tried to utilise `fill` which does not work even if pass a number of color equal to the number of rows. Also `col.ind` does not help

```
library(factoextra)   
data(iris)
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE)
fviz_pca_ind(res.pca, geom.ind = c("point", "text"),
             pointsize = 3, fill.ind="black",
             habillage=iris$Species, pointshape = 19,
             palette = c("white", "orange", "grey"),
             label = "all",
             repel = TRUE ,
             invisible="quali")
```

Comment: When you make use of functions that are not in base R, it is helpful to include a `library` statement in your sample code to inform readers of required packages.

Comment: I do not understand the question. You already filled the dots according to the groups. When you color one group white, this group will be invisible because of the white background. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have edited the question